# sum of calculate difference (time) between two records - mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with process data containing nazwa, wartosc, czas. The table data look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnh9J.jpg)

Now I wrote query:

```
;WITH [cteRows] AS
(
    SELECT  [nazwa],
            [wartosc],
            [czas],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7]
    WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
    AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
    AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
) 
SELECT  mc.[RowNumber],
        mc.[czas],
        mc.[nazwa],
        mc.[wartosc],
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.[czas], ISNULL(mp.[czas], mc.[czas])) AS [Wsekundach]
FROM [cteRows] mc 
LEFT JOIN [cteRows] mp 
    ON mc.[RowNumber] = mp.[RowNumber] + 1 
WHERE mc.[wartosc] = 0
```

And output [look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRoCT.jpg)

I have question:
How can I make one row sum of [Wsekundach] instead of present output?

Comment: As the other columns have varying data in all rows: Which information do you want to show there, if the result is reduced to one single row?

Comment: I would have information about all time difference. [Wsekundach]

Comment: Isn't that just going to be the difference between the first and the last row?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
;WITH [cteRows] AS
(
    SELECT  [nazwa],
            [wartosc],
            [czas],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7]
    WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
    AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
    AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
)

, cteNewRows AS
(
    SELECT  mc.[RowNumber],
            mc.[czas],
            mc.[nazwa],
            mc.[wartosc],
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.[czas], ISNULL(mp.[czas], mc.[czas])) AS [Wsekundach]
    FROM [cteRows] mc 
    LEFT JOIN [cteRows] mp  ON mc.[RowNumber] = mp.[RowNumber] + 1 
    WHERE mc.[wartosc] = 0 
)

SELECT  SUM(Wsekundach) AS SumOfWsekundach
FROM    cteNewRows
```

Comment: I have fault in line: 
;WITH cteNewRows AS

Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: super thanks, and could you tell me also how can I make, that when the last row has wartosc = 1 than add to [Wsekundach] how long ist between datetime of 7. rows and '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row that is the difference, I think you can use a much simpler query:

```
      SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(c.[czas]), MAX(c.[czas]) 
      FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7] c
      WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' AND
            [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' AND
            [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000' AND
            c.[wartosc] = 0;
```

Doing the sum just based on the maximum and minimum is *much* more efficient than summing up the intermediate sums.